# Как упростить цепочку промисов?

Tags: javascript, node.js, async-await, promise

Ломаю голову над промисами:

```
mariadb.createConnection(config)
    .then(connection => {
        connection.query('INSERT INTO...')
            .then(() => {
                console.log('Успешно.');
            })
            .catch(error => {
                    console.log('Не удалось.');
                    connection.end();
                    throw error;
            });
        connection.query('INSERT INTO...')
            .then(() => {
                console.log('Успешно.');
                connection.end();
            })
            .catch(error => {
                console.log('Не удалось.');
                connection.end();
                throw error;
            });
    })
    .catch(error => {
        console.log('Попытка подключения не удалась.');
        throw error;
    });
```

Нужно несколько раз записать значения в БД. Можно ли как-то вынести блок с `connection.query` в отдельную функцию чтобы уйти от дублирования?

Comment: а не будет ошибки при обращении к connection после вызова `connection.end()`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**async/await**

Можно попробовать так, если можно выполнять запросы синхронно

```js
async function doDBInsert (config) {
  let connection;
  try {
    connection = await mariadb.createConnection(config);
    try {
      await connection.query('INSERT INTO...')
      console.log('Успешно.', 1);
      await connection.query('INSERT INTO...')
      console.log('Успешно.', 2);
    } catch (error) {
      console.log('Не удалось.', error);
    } finally {
      // или тут
      connection.end();
    }
  } catch (error) {
    console.log('Попытка подключения не удалась.', error);
  } finally {
    // можно тут закрыть connection если не undefined
    // if (connection) connection.end();
  }
```

или завернуть их в Promise.all если можно запустить параллельно

```
function logError (e) {
  console.log('Не удалось.', e);
  return e;
}

await Promise.all([
  connection.query('INSERT INTO...').catch(logError),
  connection.query('INSERT INTO...').catch(logError),
]);
```